# JavaScript forEach() navigate to parent element

Tags: javascript

I deal with the following structure (in real scenario much more nested):

```
var object = {label:'a', children:[
   {label:'b', children:[]},
   {label:'c', children:[]}]
}
```

Is there a way if I use the forEach function to navigate to the parent. See this snippet for better explanation:

```
object.children.forEach(myFunc);

function myFunc(element,index){
    if(index==0){
      element.labelEdge = /* here I want the label from the object in which the array is 
      located, in this case I want the label 'a'*/ + 'Left';
    }else{
     element.labelEdge = /* here I want the label from the object in which the array is 
      located, in this case I want the label 'a'*/ + 'Right';
    }
    if(element.children){
      element.children.forEach(myFunc);
    }

}
```

Comment: By parent do you mean the array you called forEach on?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use a different approach and take the parent object for getting the label.

This proposal uses [`Array#forEach`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach) and `thisArg` of the method for referencing the parent object.

```js
function iter(object, index) {
    if ('label' in this) {
        console.log(['left', 'right'][index] + ' ' + this.label + object.label);
    }
    if (Array.isArray(object.children)) {
        object.children.forEach(iter, object);
    }
}

var object = { label: 'a', children: [{ label: 'b', children: [] }, { label: 'c', children: [] }] };

iter(object);
```

Comment: How can I use the index in the `iter()` function? `iter(index,object)`isn't working

Answer (score 1):

This is probably what you want.

```
json.children.forEach(myFunc);

function myFunc(element, index) {
    if (index === 0) {
        element.labelEdge = json.label + 'Left';
    } else {
        element.labelEdge = json.label + 'Right';
    }
}
```

But in some cases due to scope, it might not be possible to access that object(`json` here in `myFunc`), then in that case you can pass the parent object(`json`) to forEach as the second argument and it'll be reachable in the `myFunc` as the `this` object:

```
json.children.forEach(myFunc, json);

function myFunc(element, index) {
    if (index === 0) {
        element.labelEdge = this.label + 'Left';
    } else {
        element.labelEdge = this.label + 'Right';
    }
}
```

Comment: Would this approach even work if you assume that the json structure is more nested and at the end of `myFunc()`, I will recursively call `element.children.forEach(myFunc)`?

Comment: @d4rty yes it could, you would need to continue to pass`thisArg` with the appropriate value (`element` in each recursive call)

Answer (score 1):

If it's supposed to be a recursive object, I think you meant something like this:

```
var json = {label:'a', children:[
   {label:'b', children:[]},
   {label:'c', children:[]},
   {label:'f', children:[]},
   {label:'c', children:[
       {label:'cd', children:[]},
       {label:'t', children:[]}
   ]}]
}

function recursiveLabel(obj){
    obj.children.map((child)=>{
        child.label=obj.label;
        return child;
    })
    obj.children.forEach(recursiveLabel);
}

recursiveLabel(json)
console.log(json)
```

all the children would have label:'a'
at the end.